# How to set hyperlink as parent of a button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple button which I want to make it as a link using jquery , I know I can use just html like this

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">
   <div buttonid="60" class="video-btns show">Login</div>
</a>
```

But I want the same but using jquery

Here is js

```
  $(".video-btns").attr('href', "http://www.google.com");
```

Unfortunately, this is not working, what do I need to change to get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding with the way that these built in elements are designed. The anchor element is capable of automatically redirecting the browser page by use of the hyperlink reference attribute (href) when a click event is registered.

However, that is a special trait of the anchor element (`<a>`). The `href` attribute only holds the location of the target for redirection on anchor elements, and does not facilitate the relocation.

In order to programatically create a new page in the browser, you need to manually open the location yourself on a click event.

```
$(".video-btns").click(function() {
  window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate / reference the   HTML element, and in the code with jquery you are referencing the div

```
<a id="link" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">
   <div class="video-btns show">Login</div>
</a>
```

You can use an id, for example:

```
$("#link").attr('href', "http://www.google.com");
```